# SoundCloud access token's "expires_in" attribute: How is it used?

Tags: soundcloud

What does the expires_in exactly mean and how is it used?

I am getting 21599 as the expires_in value. It doesn't look like a unix timestamp nor a date in a format I can think of so I do not know how exactly this info would be useful to check whether my token has expired.

I tried looking at the following docs and I cannot find the answer to my question:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably it is in seconds (from now):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.2

It would be better if they explicitly documented the units.

Comment: That's what I figured. I wonder why they decided to not use a timestamp for that value when there could be a 1-2 second discrepancy between when the response was generated and when the response would be received. Although I can account for that as well.